# How to draw the hexagons inside the parallelogram?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to draw the following picture, which is a parallelogram and two congruent regular hexagonos.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}   
\usetkzobj{all} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=8,ymin=0,ymax=3] 
\tkzClip[space=.5] 
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(6,0){B} 
\tkzDefPoint(7.5,3){C} \tkzDefPoint(1.5,3){D}
\tkzDefPointWith[colinear= at C](B,A)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hexagon is nice since all the angles are 60 degrees, meaning all the sides a the distance from center to a corner are the same. I call this distance `\D`. Then it is mostly a matter of counting sides and angles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\D{2}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \path (A) ++(0:\D) ++(-60:\D)coordinate (B);
  %%
  \draw[fill=gray!50] ($(A)+(120:\D)$) 
  -- ($(A)+(120:\D)+(-120:3*\D)$) 
  -- ($(B)+(-60:\D)$) 
  -- ($(B)+(-60:\D)+(60:3*\D)$) -- cycle;
  %% Hexagons
  \draw[fill=white] (A) +(0:\D) -- +(60:\D)  -- +(120:\D)  -- +(180:\D) -- +(240:\D)  -- +(300:\D) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=white] (B) +(0:\D) -- +(60:\D)  -- +(120:\D)  -- +(180:\D) -- +(240:\D)  -- +(300:\D) -- cycle;
  %% Where are A and B?
  \draw (A) circle (1pt) node[below]{A};
  \draw (B) circle (1pt) node[below]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]